# How to delete core.* files while the program is running?

Tags: shell-script, core-dump

I launch my program from .sh file (for simplicity let's say it's content is just ./myprogram). For some unknown reason the program generates large core.* files. What should I add in my .sh file so that these files are being deleted while my program is running?

Comment: Can't you simply add a `rm -f core.*` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Or possibly `ulimit -c 0` or such to limit the coredump size, or fix the buggy code causing the coredumps...

Comment: You should fix your program so it doesn't generate a core dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core` files are written for post mortem of *crashed* processes, you *must* find out what is happening (a segmentation fault or other crash might signal a *serious* security vulnerability!).

As the file is written after the program crashed, they can safely be removed at any time. In any case, if you delete a file that is being held open by a process, the filesystem entry will be removed, but the process isn't affected at all.

Comment: Of course something should be fixed with the program. I should have formulated my question as "How to delete files (not necessarily core files) while the program is running". ./myprogram;  while(true) ; do rm -f core.*;done launches an infinite loop . I was expecting answers related to find a way around this.

Comment: Move `./myprogram` to inside the while loop seems like the trivial fix here... or remove the while loop. If you really meant "delete files while program is running" then put the program in the background with `&` and do `while kill -0 $!; do rm -f core.*; done`. But this is still solving the wrong problem: prevent the garbage files form being created in  the first place!